# Show that expected number of years till first observation is exceeded for first time is infinite given infinite observations

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,X_2...$ be jointly independently random variables with common pdf given by $f(x_i)$. I am trying to show that $E[N]$ is infinite, where $N$ is the number of years till $X_1$ is exceeded for the first time, and $X_i$ represents the annual rainfall in the *i*-th year.

First I obtained the distribution function for N. Since $F(X_1)$ is the probability of a particular observation being less than $X_1$, it can be shown that: $$p(N=n)=F(X_1)^{n-1}(1-F(X_1)).$$

Next, I can express the expected value of $N$ as: $$E[N]=\sum_1^\infty nF(X_1)^{n-1}(1-F(X_1))=\sum_1^\infty nF(X_1)^{n-1} - \sum_1^\infty nF(X_1)^{n}. $$

At this point, I'm not sure how to proceed. Any advice?

Comment: $p(N=n)=F(X_1)^{n-1}(1-F(X_1))$ makes no sense -- the left-hand side is a constant and the right-hand side is a random variable.

Comment: @DF: No, these events are correlated, since they all involve the same $X_1$.

Comment: @DF: They are. That doesn't mean that the events $X_i\gt X_j$ and $X_i\gt X_k$ are independent.

Comment: $X_1, X_2...$ share a common pdf but are jointly independent according to the question.

Comment: @joriki, yes, I'm sorry

Comment: @joriki I'm not sure what you mean in your first comment. The probability that N=2, for example, would be the probability of the 2nd observation being less than $X_1$ and the 3rd observation being larger than $X_1$.

Comment: @DavidS: This might be $P(N=n\mid X_1)$ (I haven't checked that), but it can't be $P(N=n)$; an equation that depends on $X_1$ on one side and not on the other makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that $N\ge n$ is the probability that $X_1$ is the greatest of the first $n$ values, which is $\frac1n$. Thus

$$
\mathsf E[N]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathsf P(N\ge n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n=\lim_{k\to\infty}H_k=\infty\;.
$$